# How to get parameter values from a test case on azure devops (former vsts) in C# tests?

Tags: azure, automated-tests, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get the parameter values defined in a test case in Azure DevOps (former VSTS). My test case looks like this- [Azure devops test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW5Zi.png)

I am trying to get the values in a test method that looks like this-

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase",
  "https://[companyName].visualstudio.com;[projectName]", 
  "5843", // this is the test case number 
  DataAccessMethod.Sequential), 
  TestMethod]
public void DataOverlapsBottomRowOfFilterFromTestParameter()
{

  string column1 = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString(); // read parameter by column index
  string column2 = TestContext.DataRow["Column2"].ToString(); //read parameter by column name 

// rest of the code

}
```

While running this test it does not even come into the test method code. It gives this error-

The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library. Error details: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

[Test method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDUxM.png)

Please, can anyone point me out what I am missing here? I have followed the Data-Driven Unit Test documentation. But I feel I might be missing something that can make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105558/how-does-data-driven-unit-test-works-to-retrieve-data-from-vsts-work-item  Have you checked with this one?

Comment: I have. It did not work I am afraid. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I got it working by using the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common and 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi namespaces.

The code goes like this

```
[TestMethod]
[WorkItem(1111)]
public void GetTestValuesFromTestParameter()
{
  //This test is for continuous range 

  var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
  var attr = (WorkItemAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WorkItemAttribute), true)[0];
  var workItemId = attr.Id;
  var dataTable = GetTableItemsFromTestCase(workItemId);
  foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
  {
    //Rest of the code
  }
}
```

GetTableItemsFromTestCase method -

```
private DataTable GetTableItemsFromTestCase(int workItemId)
{
  var accountUri = new Uri("");     // Account URL, for example: https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com                
  var personalAccessToken = ";  // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts              

  // Create a connection to the account
  var connection = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));

  // Get an instance of the work item tracking client
  var witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

  IEnumerable<XElement> descendants = new List<XElement>();
  var dt = new DataTable();
  try
  {
    // Get the specified work item
    var workitem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(workItemId).Result;

    var itemParams = workitem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Parameters"];
    var itemParamsElement = XElement.Parse((string)itemParams);

    var paramDataSource = workitem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource"];
    var xElement = XElement.Parse(paramDataSource.ToString());

    //Assuming we have a table named "Table1" in the workitem
    descendants = xElement.Descendants("Table1");

    foreach (var xe in itemParamsElement.Descendants("param"))
    {
      var name = xe.Attribute("name").Value;
      dt.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
    }
    foreach (var descendant in descendants)
    {
      var r = dt.NewRow();
      foreach (var xe in descendant.Descendants())
      {
        r[xe.Name.LocalName] = xe.Value;
      }
      dt.Rows.Add(r);
    }
  }
  catch (AggregateException aex)
  {
    VssServiceException vssex = aex.InnerException as VssServiceException;
    if (vssex != null)
    {
      //log error
    }
  }
```

I hope it helps others. Got help from this link for authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts

Comment: NIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIICE! Was looking for something like this for days....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For Adding your Solution.
I tried it but got Some Assembly Errors from GAC Fusion Prober.
But I Found an Easier Way to do that and I would like to share.

see :https://blogs.infosupport.com/accessing-test-case-parameters-in-an-associated-automation/

All you need is :

```cs
private void PrintParameterValues(ITestCase testCase, string parameterName)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in testCase.DefaultTableReadOnly.Rows)
    {
        string value = row[parameterName];
        Console.WriteLine(parameterName + " value: " + value;
    }
}
```

It Worked in My Case and I Was Able to Print out all Values from my Parameter.

You Can also Use index and not only Parameter name :

```cs
string value = row[0];
```

will also work.