# Test video recording not uploading to test result Azure Devops

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm facing an issue to upload videos of Selenium test to test result after execution in Azure devops set up.

This is simple and straight forward, by using VSTS Task - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/collect-screenshots-and-video?view=azure-devops

This was working fine, until I've started to read parameters from Test Case and passing to my Automated test by using https://github.com/l3oferreira/MSTest.AzureDevOps

When ever i tried to read parameters from the test, it fails to upload the videos, but when I don't use it, it successfully upload the videos to test.

Observed that, in either cases, it successfully records the video, but only fails to upload to test in the later.

Comment: How did it go with this case? Any update

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT the issue was with the test agent, reinstalling did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get parameters from Test Case with package MSTest.AzureDevOps. But it failed with error cannot find my account.

You can have a try writing your own code using API to get the parameters from Test Case and pass them to automated tests. please check here for [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560461/how-to-get-parameter-values-from-a-test-case-on-azure-devops-former-vsts-in-c).